# Determining how well a curve fits data

Tags: statistics

What are some commonly used ways to examine how well a curve fits a given set of data?
 I am aware of the R Squared test but I was wondering if there are other tests that take into account the appearance of the curves as well.

To be more precise, I am trying to model the spread of diseases using various methods such as the classic differential equation SI model as well as others that take into account a bit of network structure. The latter models have a distinctly different appearance than the S shape of the SI model.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question needs to be clarified. Take account how? (And what shape is it?)....  $R^2$ often isn't a good way to compare fits (especially nonlinear ones). If the number of parameters are equal in each case, why not just MSE?